# Ionic DomSanitizer doesn't work for bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

It gives me the error  `GET http://localhost:8100/null 404 (Not Found)`
I have tried multiple DomSanitizer methods, but none of them work for some reason .

My controller function is

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,  public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 ionViewWillEnter() {
  let link = this.navParams.get('link'); // gets the link to be sanitized
  console.log(link); //works
  let url1 = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(link);
  console.log(url1); //works
}
```

My iframe code is

```
<iframe [src]="url1" height="100%" width="100%"
  frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
```

My Setup -
Ionic 3.20.0
npm 5.5.0

Comment: did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem and from what I'm reading the issue is specific to `iframe` use.

Comment: I fixed it. 
Just declare the url variable as a "TrustResourceUrl" type

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your lifecycle? Maybe your view is getting a `null` or `undefined` for `url1`. It works for me when I initialize in my constructor or even in the `ionViewDidLoad()` method

Comment: The data is passed to the view perfectly too. I printed the url as plaintext and it appeared without any issues

Answer (score 0):

Your "url1" is not a declared as **public**. In that case, the html template won't be able to pick it up.

Try this way.

```
public url1: any;
...
constructor(...)
...
ionViewWillEnter(){
...
    this.url1=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the url variable as a "TrustResourceUrl" type